# Непонятная конструкция в SCSS

Tags: css, sass, scss

Скажите пожалуйста, как называется эта конструкция, на которую направлена стрелка? А именно #{$cols}n Автор объяснил только то, что она непосредственно обратится к последней колонке и задаст свой стиль, но как называется такой синтаксис ( регулярные выражения ?)  и для чего используется -  промолчал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас входящая переменная `$cols` у миксина, вот ее значение и выводится.

Comment: Спасибо, но а что это за конструкция такая? #{$cols}n , как этот синтаксис называется?

Comment: Я бы предположил, что это способ обращения к переменной - надо её отделить от буквы `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@mixin`](https://webref.ru/layout/sass/mixin) это своего рода функция, как например в JS.

Допустим если использовать правило

```
.cols {
  @import grid(10, 5px); /* $cols, $margin */
}
```

То блок `.cols` получит следующие правила

```
.cols {
  float: left;
  background: #ce3d3d;
  margin-right: 5px;  /* $margin */
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* $margin */
  height: 150px;
}

.cols:nth-child(10n) { /* $cols */
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

А конструкция `${}` в ней является [интерполяцией](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/sassscript/interpolyatsiya/) переменной.

> Вы также можете использовать переменные SassScript в селекторах и в названиях свойств используя синтаксис `#{}` интерполяции

Comment: вы заметили, что стрелка указывает не на конструкцию `@mixin` а на `#{$cols}` ? Автор не спрашивает, что такое миксин.

Comment: Спасибо, но я имел в виду #{$cols}n

Comment: @РусланКамов, дополнил ответ

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 спасибо большое за очень полезные ссылки и ответ

Comment: @РусланКамов, не за что, удачи в обучение

Answer (score 4):

из документации:

> *Interpolation* can be used almost anywhere in a Sass stylesheet to embed the result of a SassScript expression into a chunk of CSS. Just wrap an expression in `#{}` in any of the following places:
>
> - Selectors in style rules
> - Property names in declarations
> - Custom property values
> - CSS at-rules
> - @extends
> - Plain CSS @imports
> - Quoted or unquoted strings
> - Special functions
> - Plain CSS function names
> - Loud comments

вы не можете втыкать переменные `$var` в произвольные места scss-файла, так что для этих целей следует обернуть выражения в `#{}` чтобы отделить их от других частей строки.

на русском - https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/sassscript/interpolyatsiya/

аналогично, напримре, встраивание переменной внутри строки в php, `string {$var}string` устраняет возможные неоднозначности.

Comment: Вот уже потихоньку лёд тронулся, только почему в конце n стоит?

Comment: @РусланКамов, для этого нужно изучить основы CSS - [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: @РусланКамов потому что селектор css выглядит как `:nth-child(An+B)`.

Comment: @teran . Вы извините , я Вас не понимаю. Я знаю что :nth-child() обращается к конкретному элементу в блоке. Внутри скобок пишется номер элемента по порядку или специальные значения такие как odd или even. Но :nth-child(An+B). я не пойму

Comment: @РусланКамов вам выше в коментарии дали ссылку на документацию по nth-child, ознакомьтесь. Если третий записывается как `:nth-child(3)`, то каждый третий записывается как `3n`, например. Четные можно записать как even|odd, но можно и в виде функции 2n/2n+1. Первые три, например, можно описать в виде `3-n`. и так далее.

Comment: @teran спасибо большое, я Вас понял теперь